# set :defore css property in angular based on data

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i want to set :before property data of my html class in angular below is my html content and i want to set data if some condition true

```
<div class="back">
                                    <div class="letter">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flap left-flap"></div>
                                    <div class="flap right-flap"></div>
                                    <div class="flap bottom-flap"></div>
                                    <div class="flap top-flap"></div>
                                </div>
```

i want to set top-flap:before css property data if some variable data is true